# unknown data type in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-cloud-platform

I have below code to access secret manager

```
export interface ConfigData {
dbname:string;
dbuser:string;
}
```

I hvae json data in secret manager like

```
{
"dbname" : "dbname",
"dbuser" : "dbuser"
}
```

**function**

```
private static async fetchSecretData(){
     let config_key = 'projects/xx/xx/xx/versions/latest';
    
       const client = new SecretManagerServiceClient();
       const [version] = await client.accessSecretVersion({name:config_key})
       console.log(version.payload?.data )
       return version.payload?.data?.toString() as unknown as ConfigData;
 }
```

But I need to cast this as unknown as ConfigData,

I want to cast this ConfigData without making it unknown.

If there is no alternate to do this, then what is the best option to get the keys from this unknown object.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two remarks:

- `toString()` will return a `string` representation of whatever `data` is, so casting this to any other type is not going work.
- It looks like `SecretManagerServiceClient` is a part of the [Google Cloud Secret Manager API](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/secretmanager/latest/v1beta1.SecretManagerServiceClient.html). You don't have to provide your own types for those as the `@google-cloud/secret-manager` package already comes with its own type definitions.
- From from this package, I can tell that the payload is typed like this:

```
                /** Properties of a SecretPayload. */
                interface ISecretPayload {

                    /** SecretPayload data */
                    data?: (Uint8Array|string|null);
                }
```

To me it's not quite clear what this `data` is supposed to be. If it's a JSON string then you need to parse it with `JSON.parse(version.payload.data)` and then append  `as ConfigData` to that, to let TypeScript know the shape of the output. If it's a `Uint8Array` you need to `.toString` it first before parsing it with `JSON.parse`.

So you would get something like:

```
private static async fetchSecretData() {
    let config_key = 'projects/xx/xx/xx/versions/latest';
    const client = new SecretManagerServiceClient();
    const [version] = await client.accessSecretVersion({name:config_key})
    if(version?.payload?.data) {
        return JSON.parse(version.payload.data) as ConfigData
    } else {
        return null;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Yes this googel cloud secrete manager api, i want to provide my own types for easily accessing properties like .dbname e.t.c

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Can you see what `version.payload.data` actually contains? E.g. by inspecting it with a debugger or printing it to console with `console.log`? I think you may need to do some post processing like `JSON.parse` but I am not sure.